# Replacing Class.forName method call in ASM (inline)

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to capture the classes being loaded by replacing each method call to Class.forName in the place where the method is called (a callback in the method is not an option). i.e

```
...
Class.forName(className);
...
```

is replaced by

```
...
Class.forName(MyProxy.call(className));
...
```

My problem is trying to do the same with Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) method. My idea would be to do the following:

Class.forName(MyProxy.call(className), booleanParameter, classLoaderParameter)

However, I don't find a way to do this. Using and invokeStatic is not an option because Class.forName will not work properly if classes are protected for example

Comment: When you replace an `invokevirtual` by an `invokestatic`, you have to consider the receiver object, as otherwise there is no way to perform the original call inside your new target method. Therefore, the `call` method must have an additional first parameter taking the receiver. Then, letting this method consume all arguments and the receiver, is no problem as that’s what the invocation is supposed to do. Inside your `call` method, the parameters are local variables which you can access by index. There is no point where you need a `dup` instruction.

Comment: You are right we are passing the original object in other calls. I've just updated the question with the exact situation because it was not properly written

Comment: You can not do delegation to `MyProxy.call`, as then, `Class.forName` will see a different caller class. But you can insert a new helper method into the class you’re instrumenting, which will then invoke `MyProxy.call(className)`, followed by `Class.forName(className, booleanArg, classLoader)`. Since that call happens in the helper method in the original class, `Class.forName` will see the right caller class. Then, you only have to change the target of the `invokestatic` method. But keep in mind, there are tons of potential triggers for class loading…

Comment: Yes, that's why I try to insert MyProxy.call() before calling the Class.forName in the class. My problem is that I don't find any way to get the first parameter to be inserted in my method call. When 2 o less parameters are used DUPXX can be used for that

Comment: It seems you missed the point of my comment; when inserting a new synthetic method into the class, to be called in place of `Class.forName`, the on-stack parameters become local variables in the new method, which can be accessed by index, hence, the code of that method is trivial.

Comment: Ok, now I get the idea, creating a new method for this is strange but... it may work, I will try to implement it and let you know

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Holger suggestion I was able to find a solution, finally my code replaces:

```
...
Class.forName(className, booleanParameter, loader);
...
```

With

```
...
__callClassForName(className, booleanParameter, loader);
...

private static Class __callClassForName(String className, boolean bParameter, ClassLoader loader) {
    MyProxy.call(className);
    return Class.forName(className, bParameter, loader);
}
```